# How to list function definition in windbg like gdb?

Tags: windbg

In gdb I can simply `list func` to see the definition of `func`,

and the lines increments each time.But in windbg I tried `lsa func`,

it sometimes works,but sometimes not.And even when it's working,the line doesn't increment each time I press return.

How do you check code with windbg(assume debug symbols are loaded)?

Comment: @Seva Titov,it's built from visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff552114.aspx

Make sure that .lines is toggled on. You can then use l+s to display source each time you step with the debugger. You can then step through the code and source lines will be printed as you step.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff552107(v=VS.85).aspx

If you want to view the lines wihtout actuall stepping the program do lsa func to start viewing the function this will also set the current line. You can continue viewing lines by doing lsa by itself.