# How to list function source in windbg when debug symbols are loaded?

Tags: gdb, windbg

I came from gdb,where I can symbolly list the source by `l func`,then press enter to see more of the definition.

How to do this in windbg?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list function definition in windbg like gdb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927111/how-to-list-function-definition-in-windbg-like-gdb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disassemble func type `u func` if you want to open the source type `.open -a func`

If you want to list source in the command window or in cdb use `lsa func`

you can replace func with an address.

Answer (score 0):

Just go File->Open Source File..

[image]

Comment: What if there's only .pdb,no source file?